# How to delete an array item in meteor using mongo?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I have this app I'm working on...

http://stevedavis.meteor.com/

You can see the contents of the group collection by doing a 'Groups.find()' in the console.

I have this in my JS...

```
Template.listGroups.events({
  'click .deleteMember': function(){
    var groupID = this.groupID,
        firstName = this.firstName,
        lastName = this.lastName;
  }
});
```

So, I wanna be able to delete a member from a group if I click the X next to their name. I've tried...

```
Groups.update( {"_id": groupID }, {$unset: { "members" : {"firstName": firstName, "lastName": lastName} } } );
```

but it removed ALL members. I only want it to remove the members item that matches the first and last name of the element clicked. Thanks.

Comment: seems to be a duplicate of your question about removing the same element from multiple documents...

Answer (score 10):

Ah, I just had to change "$unset" to "$pull". I added via "$push" so I thought, "Is there a $pull method?" And there was! :)

```
Groups.update( {"_id": groupID }, {"$pull": { "members" : {"firstName": firstName, "lastName": lastName} } } );
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this awesome page in MongoDB's documentation that shows the query / projection you discovered here plus many many more!

[MongoDB documentation.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-array/)

Thank you for asking this - your answer got me on the right track.